# Can you ignore HTML in a string while doing a Replace with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replace words in a string, but ignore HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503121/replace-words-in-a-string-but-ignore-html)

Is it possible to ignore the HTML elements when calling Replace?

Sample code:

```
$myText.replace(new RegExp( $searchString, 'gi' ), 
    '<span class="highlight">'+ $searchString + '</span>');
```

`$myText` is a large string of HTML e.g.:

```
var $myText = 
    "<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting " +
    "industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text " +
    "ever since the 1500s, <img src="something">when an unknown printer " +
    "took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. " +
    "It has survived not only five centuries, " +
    "<a href="#" title="Lorem">but</a> also the leap into electronic " +
    "typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in " +
    "the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum " +
    "passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like " +
    "Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>"
```

`$searchString` is equal to whatever a user types into an text input box.

If yes, how would I do it given the above sample code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, take a look at the following forum post:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1443955.aspx

The RegEx pattern you are looking for would be something similar to the following:

```
"(?<!<[^>]*)Jon Doe(?<![^>]*<)"
```

Basically, you're doing a search and replace on anything that lives outside brackets <>.

JavaScript:

```
phrase = phrase.replace(/"(?<!<[^>]*)Jon Doe(?<![^>]*<)" /i, "is not");
```

Comment: In jQuery terms, you would use the above RegEx expression in the following manner:

phrase = phrase.replace(/"(?<!<[^>]*)Jon Doe(?<![^>]*<)"
/i, "is not");

Comment: but won't a stray > in the text mess everything up? or malformed html where they just use a <p> in one instance and a <p>text</p> elsewhere?

Comment: Nope. Your only ignoring content that is within a tag - <ignore this here>don't ignore this</ignore this too>

Comment: unless for some reason they decided to include html code as part of their text input.

Comment: I have tried it a few times keep getting an invalid quantifier ?<!<[^>]*)Jon Doe(?<![^>]*<)" error from Firebug.

when using this:

$myText.replace(/"(?<!<[^>]*)Jon Doe(?<![^>]*<)" /i, '<span class="mdHighlight">'+ $searchString + '</span>');

Comment: you are awesome brother save my day!!!

Answer (score 1):

Parsing HTML with a regular expression? [This isn't a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/50776). I would suggest inserting the HTML into the DOM and then traversing the nodes.