# JavaScript converting plain text to links && smilies

Tags: javascript, regex, mootools

Working example: http://alpha.jsfiddle.net/gTpWv/

Both of the methods work separately, but once regexp for smilies gets raw HTML code to process, things get ugly.

```
    K = K.replace(/\b((http:\/\/)|(www\.))[^ ]{5,}/g, function (x) {
    var b = x;
    if (b.indexOf("www") == 0) {
        b = "http://" + b
    }
    return '<a href="' + b + '" target="_blank">' + x + "</a>"
// K is now /"Testing <a href="http://www.google.com," target="_blank">http://www.google.com,</a> :D, ^^"/


    for (var d = 0; d < smiliesArray.length; d++) {
        K = K.replace(new RegExp(smiliesArray[d][0], "g"), '<img src="' + smiliesArray[d][1] + '">');
    }
// K is now Testing <a href="http%3Cimg%20src=" http:="" i.imgur.com="" mvk87.gif"="">/www.google.com," target="_blank"&gt;http<img src="http://i.imgur.com/MVk87.gif">/www.google.com,</a> <img src="http%3Cimg%20src=" http:="" i.imgur.com="" mvk87.gif"="">/i.imgur.com/7JJNL.gif"&gt;, <img src="http%3Cimg%20src=" http:="" i.imgur.com="" mvk87.gif"="">/i.imgur.com/vRgA3.gif"&gt;
```

I did find [regexp claiming to solve this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2289688/1188585), but inserting it into the regexp: http://alpha.jsfiddle.net/gTpWv/1/ returns nothing.

I've also found interesting the idea to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/822486) procedure, but I would be left with two seperate lines, one with links and one with smilies and it would take another regexp to inject one into another.

I'm not sure should I meddle with a better regexp(s) or try to find another way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `:/` will be caught in places where it shouldn't. Every time `K` changes during replaces, it is fed with some `http://` strings that contain the seeds of evil... the **`:/`** bits. At the next iteration, these will be replaced with the corresponding [image] smilie, corrupting the generated HTML stored in `K`.

My approach was to do a 2-phase search and replace. See it in action here http://alpha.jsfiddle.net/gTpWv/7/, and read on for further explanation.

We start by changing every url and smilie to intermediate forms. To use your example string `"Testing www.google.com, :D, ^^ :/"`:

```
$each(N.split("\n"), function(K) {
    // First pass: creating url and smilie maps
    var urlSubstitutions = [];
    var smilieSubstitutions = [];

    K = K.replace(/\b((http:\/\/)|(www\.))[^ ]{5,}/g, function(match) {
        var b = match;
        if (b.indexOf("www") == 0) {
            b = "http://" + b
        }

        urlSubstitutions.push({ anchor: match, url: b });
        return "{{_u_" + urlSubstitutions.length + "_}}";
    });

    for (var d = 0; d < smiliesArray.length; d++) {
        K = K.replace(new RegExp(smiliesArray[d][0], "g"), function(x){
            smilieSubstitutions.push({ smilie: x, image: smiliesArray[d][1] });
            return "{{_s_" + smilieSubstitutions.length + "_}}";
        });
    }
```

By now, K will contain **Testing {{_u_1_}} {{_s_1_}}, {{_s_2_}} {{_s_3_}}**. I hope it's clear that these {{}} strings are the aforementioned intermediate forms of urls and smilies.  The actual values of these strings are stored in two arrays named `urlSubstitutions` and `smilieSubstitutions`. The next step is simply to decode the intermediate forms into their formatted versions:

```
    // Second pass: applying urls and smilies
    K = K.replace(/{{_u_(\d+)_}}/g, function(match, index) {
        var substitution = urlSubstitutions[parseInt(index)-1];
        return '<a href="' + substitution.url + '" target="_blank">' + substitution.anchor + "</a>";
    });

    K = K.replace(/{{_s_(\d+)_}}/g, function(match, index) {
        var substitution = smilieSubstitutions[parseInt(index)-1];
        return '<img src="' + substitution.image + '">';
    });

    document.write(K)
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, a very interesting method you've accomplished, and a very clean one, too!